# FusionCharts integration with requirejs

Tags: angularjs, charts, requirejs, fusioncharts

I am trying to use fusion charts in my angular project. I am using version 3.6.0. Now I am trying to integrate it into my project using requirejs. But its giving me the [scripterror](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror). Here is what I tried:

These are the requirejs options in Gruntfile.js

```
        paths: {
            . . . 
            . . .
            "jquery": "../js/vendors/jquery.min",
            . . .
            . . .
            "fusioncharts": "../js/vendors/fusioncharts"
        },
        shim: {
            . . .
            "fusioncharts": {
                exports: "fusioncharts",
                deps: ["jquery"]
            }
        }
```

And here is how my app starts:

```
define([
    . . .
    'fusioncharts'
], function (angular) {
```

After this, im getting this error:

[image]

Where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Are you using the minified version of angular? If you do, switch it up. The non-minified version gives better error messages.

Comment: Try using the FusionCharts plugin for AngularJS projects: http://www.fusioncharts.com/angularjs-charts/
Additionally, you can find this one on Bower:
https://github.com/SunGard-Labs/angular-fusioncharts